# How to use condition on mouse over function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<ul>
<li class="selected" id="<?php echo $idvalue;?>">link1
    <ul>
         <li>sub - Link1</li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="<?php echo $idvalue;?>">link2
    <ul>
         <li>sub - Link2</li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Friends I am not expert in jquery, I need to find "**selected**" class from **li** tag on mouse over and use following condition

```
if($("#<?php echo $idvalue;?>").find('.selected'))
        {
            alert('if cond');
            $(this).find('ul').css({"display":"block"});
        }
        else
        {
            alert('else cond');
            $(this).find('ul').css({"display":"none"});
        }
```

How should i achieve this, please share your ideas

Comment: why do you need jquery? Why not just use CSS and `:hover` [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: First off, you can't have more than 1 element with the same ID. They're unique.

Comment: @starvator yeah i got through css, i forgot that

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**:

```
li ul { display: none; }

li.selected:hover ul { display: block; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selected").on("mouseenter",funtion(){
if($("#<?php echo $idvalue;?>").find('.selected'))
        {
            alert('if cond');
            $(this).find('ul').css({"display":"block"});
        }
        else
        {
            alert('else cond');
            $(this).find('ul').css({"display":"none"});
        }

})
```

Comment: Manish i got it through css, any way i will try with the above code